# can't get values of .env file variable with getenv and GET request with $_GET

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

I am building a weather site for myself, and in order to hide my API key, I tried to send a request to the API with php on the back-end side, and for this I tried to first get values such as the name of the city from js file and API key from .env file to make requests with them, and finally get the API answers with js from php file and show them on the site.

but when I want to get this values its give me undefined or blank string , so I test some ways to fix this but it didn't help.

this is my HTML file :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/a076d05399.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./assets/css/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./assets/css/responsive.css">
    <script src="./main.js" defer></script>
    <title>weather site</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="weather-app">
        <div class="container">
            <h3 class="brand">the weather</h3>
            <div>
                <h1 class="temp">16&#176;</h1>
                <div class="city-time">
                    <h1 class="name">London</h1>
                    <small>
                        <span class="time">06:10</span>
                        <span class="date">
                            mondey sep 19
                        </span>
                    </small>
                </div>
                <div class="weather">
                    <img src="./assets/img/icon/day/113.png" class="icon" alt="icon" width="50" height="50">
                    <span class="condition">cloudy</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel">
            <form action="" id="locationInput">
                <input type="text" placeholder="search location..." class="search">
                <button type="submit" class="submit">
                    <i class="fas fa-search"></i>
                </button>
            </form>
            <ul class="cities">
                <li class="city">New York</li>
                <li class="city">California</li>
                <li class="city">Paris</li>
                <li class="city">Tokyo</li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="details">
                <h4>Weather Details</h4>
                <li>
                    <span>Cloudy</span>
                    <span class="cloud">89%</span>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <span>Humidity</span>
                    <span class="Humidity">64%</span>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <span>Wind</span>
                    <span class="Wind">8Km/h</span>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

this is my js file :

```
//Get evey necessary elements from the DOM
const app = document.querySelector('.weather-app');
const temp = document.querySelector('.temp');
const dateOutput = document.querySelector('.date');
const timeOutput = document.querySelector('.time');
const conditionOutput = document.querySelector('.condition');
const nameOutput = document.querySelector('.name');
const icon = document.querySelector('.icon');
const cloudOutput = document.querySelector('.cloud');
const HumidityOutput = document.querySelector('.Humidity');
const windOutput = document.querySelector('.wind');
const form = document.getElementById('locationInput');
const search = document.querySelector('.search');
const btn = document.querySelector('.submit');
const cities = document.querySelectorAll('.city');

//Default city when page loads
let cityInput = "London";

//Add click event to each city in the panel
for (let i = 0; i < cities.length; i++) {

    cities[i].addEventListener('click', (e) => {

        cityInput = e.target.innerHTML;

        // Get data from API
        fetchweatherdata();

        app.style.opacity = "0";
    })
}


//Add submit event to the form
form.addEventListener("submit", (e) => {
    if (search.value.length == 0) {
        alert("please type in a city name")
    } else {
        cityInput = search.value;

        // Get data from API
        //fetchweatherdata();

        search.value = "";
        app.style.opacity = "0";
    }
    e.preventDefault();
})

function dayOfTheWeek(day, month, year) {
    const weekday = [
        "Sunday",
        "Monday",
        "Tuesday",
        "Wednesday",
        "Thursday",
        "Friday",
        "Saturday"
    ];

    return weekday[new Date("${day}/${month}/${year}").getDay()];
}

function fetchweatherdata() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "./backend.php",
        data: { city: cityInput },
        success: function (response) {
            
            console.log(response);

        },
        error: function (error) {

            console.log(error);

        }
    });
}
```

this is php file :

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: application/json');

require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php'; // Path to Composer autoloader

$dotenv = Dotenv\Dotenv::createUnsafeImmutable(__DIR__);
$dotenv->load();

$apiKey = getenv('API_KEY');
$city = $_GET['city'];


$url = "https://api.weatherapi.com/v1/current.json?key=".$apiKey."&q=".$city."&aqi=no";

$data = file_get_contents($url);


echo $data;
?>
```

I use ajax method to send city name with GET request to php file and the function in js that use GET method is called fetchweatherdata and all of this files wtih .env file are in the same directory .

for testing my codes I use `php -S 127.0.0.1:8000` and want to get response data in json format to use it on my js file but now I can't get value of city and API key to send request

thanks

Comment: For debugging this, completely ignore JavaScript. You have a PHP file that you can access at a URL, just hit it directly with your browser, and make sure that PHP error reporting is set to scream at everything and display. You've got weird slashes in your posted code, too. According to the [docs](https://github.com/vlucas/phpdotenv#putenv-and-getenv), you need to call `createUnsafeImmutable` if you want to use `getenv`

Comment: @ChrisHass  I use createUnsafeImmutable in php code and check the 
URL (http://127.0.0.1:8000/backend.php) but there is nothing in the page , only this warning in console : 
`DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for chrome-extension://himepoeelnlpnhphkplaeknfejmpemll/sm/ab60d7fb9bf5b5ded42c77782b65b071de85f56c21da42948364d6b2b1961762.map: System error: net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT`

Comment: Try running `var_dump($dotenv->load());` which should show you all of the environment variables found. (I think. I've never used that library but the source code says that should happen.) Also, because you are in the browser, and not JS, put some additional `echo` statements for debugging purposes, such as `echo 'Using API key: ' . $apiKey;` and `echo 'Calling URL: ' . $url;`

Comment: @ChrisHass  looks like now I can get API key but for city name its just blank , when I use echo for city name its just show nothing

Comment: Are you passing that in the query string?

Comment: @ChrisHaas I use data in $.ajax method like in the fetchweatherdata function